# JTextField: Cannot enter text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, install4j

We are facing an issue with JTextFiled in install4j as we are not able enter anything into this after when build file runs. We are using JDK1.7 and build file is run in install using exported display to windows system. We found sometime it's editable and some times not editable even with JDK 1.6, but ultimately we need this to work with JDK1.7 only.

Appreciate your help. Command info is provided below:

oraclehostip = ((JTextField)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("APP_HOST").getConfigurationObject()).getText();

The idea is enter app host into this filed during installation and we have several fields like this we couldn't enter in any of the field.

Comment: On what OS is this? Do you have any settings that might disable the text field, like a check box with coupled form components?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late reply. We are using 2007 windows to make build file using install4j. We don't have any check box coupled form components. The observation is JTextfiled edit is not consistent. Some times it works and some times it doesn't and like a disabled field. BTW we are using trial version of install4j. Is that the problem for this issue? We are still struggling with the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this and I have not heard of similar issues. Please contact support with a sample project that exhibits this issue.

Comment: Hi, Could you pl tell me how do I contact support team? I'm in US and can talk to them. This is blocking our installer preparation. Pl help.

Comment: support@ej-technologies.com